# Print result in multiple lines

Tags: bash

I tried to find log files under `/usr/`

```
$ echo /usr/**/log
/usr/bin/log /usr/lib/log /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/doc/rubygems-2.7.6/ri/Gem/Resolver/Molinillo/DependencyGraph/log /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/share/ri/2.5.0/system/Gem/Resolver/Molinillo/DependencyGraph/log
```

It print in one line hard to read,

```
$ for i in /usr/**/log; do echo $i; done
/usr/bin/log
/usr/lib/log
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/doc/rubygems-2.7.6/ri/Gem/Resolver/Molinillo/DependencyGraph/log
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/share/ri/2.5.0/system/Gem/Resolver/Molinillo/DependencyGraph/log
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/share/ri/2.5.0/system/WEBrick/log
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/log
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/doc/rubygems-2.7.6/ri/Gem/Resolver/Molinillo/DependencyGraph/log
/usr/local/var/log
/usr/share/zsh/5.3/help/log
```

Instead of the structured  codes, is there a one line solution.

Comment: Make an effort to research more into your problems rather than posting really trivial questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` with format specifier included to print the string with the new-line character. Also always safe to quote the variables in shell script unless you have a good reason not to.

Also turn on the `nullglob` option to ignore un-expanded glob matches

```
shopt -s nullglob
printf '%s\n' /usr/**/log
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find`:

```
find /usr -name log
```

This would be a portable way of finding the pathnames of all entries whose name is `log` anywhere in or under the `/usr` directory.  To restrict to regular files only, add `-type f`:

```
find /usr -type f -name log
```

---

`echo` prints all its operands on a single line, separated by a space character, and delimited at the end by a newline.  This is why you don't get multi-line output from your first command.

Comment: find is powerful, but it's not portable to other language such as python. Apply wildcards and regex, could think about a problem any time in any language.

Comment: @Sawajiri I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "portable to Python".